Snowflake MERGE queries getting BLOCKED
We ran a load test Snowflake as the database. This run was done on 2nd & 3rd May 2024. We benchmarked our system to 35 requests per minute due to MERGE statements blocking the tables. For numbers less than 35 it was working perfectly fine.
But all of a sudden, the 35 requests per minute load test started showing regressive results, with MERGE statements getting BLOCKED. The code is the same (we have tagged our code for a particular release), package versions are same, & load test scenarios are same. The situation has worsened to the point that loads like 20 & even 10 are getting failed.
I have tried upgrading the snowflake-sdk but no gain.
Tech stack:

AWS API Gateway + Lambda with Nodejs
Artillery for load testing

I tried reducing the load but surprisingly at lower load it is failing. I also tried upgrading the snowflake-sdk but didn't work.
Question is: Why is when doing load test at two different points in time yields different results?

I am sorry, but what is your question?

It's hard to answer this on Stack Overflow if you give us no way to reproduce the situation, nor the exact error code that you got when "blocked". If this is particular to your account and no one can reproduce - please contact support instead.

amount of data increased? Table size increased ? Bad quality data/duplicates/bad joins caused by bad data/ change in data that caused the SQL to consume more memory. You can start from the question what changed after last successful run ?

@SimeonPilgrim just edited the post with Questions at the end.

Same warehouse size?  Is the warehouse isolated for this workload?  MERGE is a blocking function and they can queue.  You should look at the queue time for your previous runs to see if that is happening.
